# why the setter of var for KVO crashed (swift 2.2)?

Tags: ios, swift2, key-value-observing

I'm using KVO for manual notifications, but why the code crashed for the reason:

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff577bcfa8)" when click
>   run?

Please see below the codes:

`ChildrenViewController.swift` (class to be observed)

```
import UIKit
class ChildrenViewController: UIViewController {

dynamic var name: String? {
    get {
        return ""
    }

    set {
        willChangeValueForKey("name")
        guard let value = newValue else {return}
        self.setValue(value, forKey: "name") //crashed here!SAID "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff577bcfa8)"
        didChangeValueForKey("name")
    }

}

dynamic var age = 0

var child: ChildrenViewController?

override class func automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
    if key == "name" {
        return false
    }
    return super.automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey(key)
}

}
```

`ViewController.swift` (the observer)

```
import UIKit

private var child1Context = 1

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var child1 = ChildrenViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.child1.setValue("George", forKey: "name")
    self.child1.setValue(15, forKey: "age")
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    child1.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "name", options: [.New,.Old], context: &child1Context)
    child1.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "age", options: [.New, .Old], context: &child1Context)

    self.child1.name = "Michael" //set the name String
    self.child1.setValue(20, forKey: "age")
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.child1.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "name")
    self.child1.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "age")
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if context == &child1Context {
        if keyPath == "name" {
            print("The name of FIRST has been changed, \(change)")
        }
        if keyPath == "age" {
            print("The age of FIRST has been changed, \(change)")
        }
    }               
    }

}
```

Comment: try to extract `deinit` code to outside of `observeValueForKeyPath` function.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to type a }, actually the code is right in Xcode, the question has been revised.

Comment: remove observers within `deinit` method is a bad solution. If you will forward to next screen and return back, you view controller add observer again and it will have 2 observers and `deinit` will not help you.

Comment: i delete the `deinit`, and move the `removeObserver` to `viewWillDisappear`, but still crash for the same reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting value of `name` in **it's own setter** by this line:

```
self.setValue(value, forKey: "name")
```

Why can't do this:

```
private var _name: String?//create private variable to hold value
dynamic var name: String? {
    get {
        return _name
    }

    set {
        willChangeValueForKey("name")
        guard let value = newValue else {return}
        _name = value
        didChangeValueForKey("name")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added `addObserver` in `viewWillAppear` method, so it means you added it every time when your screen is show. For this case you need call `removeObserver` in `viewWillDisappear` method

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.child1.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "name")
    self.child1.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "age")
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Comment: Thank your answer. I tried your suggestion, also commented the deinit() function, but the app still crashed for the same reason.

Comment: Please look my comment below your answer about deinit